# (Performance) How fast is V8 in nodejs when iterating through thousands of properties in an object?

Tags: node.js, performance, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I am implementing a solution using socketio to check if the next socket connecting with a token containing a username already exists in an object (connectedUsers[token.username]). Believing hundreds of thousands of users are connected, every time I run this line:

```
if(connectedUsers[token.username]) { //the user exists }
```

how optimized is V8 in fetching the property?
Do I need to implement a binary tree or any other algorithm to optimize property fetch?
How to scale a server strong enough in the cloud knowing hundreds of users are going to fetch before connecting?

Comment: There is no real answer to "how optimized is V8 in fetching the property".  That could only be answered in comparison to something else.  Property access in V8 is super fundamental to all of V8's performance.  A ton of development has been put into making it perform.  So, your question can really only be answered in comparison to some other option when running some specific performance measuring tests to compare the two.  Personally, I'd probably use a `Map` or `Set` object myself.

Comment: FYI, there are many different optimization paths in V8 for property access too so performance may even depend upon how you've written your code and what optimizations V8 feels it can use with that code.  These optimizations can make a big difference.  These optimizations change over time as V8 versions change.